# php preg_split: split string by lowercase letters surrounded by undrscores

Tags: php, regex

I need to split a string by lowercase letters surrounded by underscores while keeping the delimiter.  For example, if I have this string:
`$string = '1_and_2_not_3';`
The desired output would be:

```
[
  0 => "1",
  1 => "_and_2",
  2 => "_not_3"
]
```

Right now, I'm doing this:
`$stringArray = preg_split('/[_(.*?)_]/u', $string, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`
However, it's not capturing the whole delimiter and its only catching the first match.

```
[
  0 => "1",
  1 => "and_2_not_3"
]
```

What regex expression would catch all matches plus give me the full delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split using a lookahead, asserting the position of an underscore then lowercase letter.

```
$results = preg_split('/(?=_[a-z])/', $str);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/495153)

Comment: That should work, but for some reason, preg_split is not splitting globally for me. Im still getting '_and_2_not_3' as the second item in the results array.

Comment: Never mind.  Removing PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE solved the problem.